# How to iteratively fill pandas Dataframe with columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe with iteratively counting statisitcs from another dataframe, it goes through columns (that filtered with regex). How could i create a result Dataframe?
Input dataframe:

```
    In [4]: control.head()
    Out[4]:
  Patient Gender  Age  Left-Lateral-Ventricle_NVoxels  Left-Inf-Lat- 
Vent_NVoxels  ...  supramarginal_CurvInd_lh
0    P008      M   30                            9414                        
311  ...                       7.5
1    P013      F   35                            7668                         
85  ...                      10.4
2    P018      F   27                            7350                        
202  ...                       8.0
3    P033      F   55                            7548                        
372  ...                       9.2
4    P036      F   31                            8598                         
48  ...                       8.0

    [5 rows x 930 columns]
```

I wrote a code to count statistic, but stuck on creating result pandas dataframe

```
def select_volumes(group_c,group_k):
    Select_list = ["Amygdala", "Hippocampus", "Lateral-Ventricle", 
"Pallidum", "Putamen", "Thalamus"]
    Side = ["Left", "Right"]
    for s in Side:
        for struct in Select_list:
            volumes_c = group_c.filter(regex="^(?=.*"+s+")(?=.*"+struct+") 
   (?=.*Volume)")
            volumes_k = group_k.filter(regex="^(?=.*"+s+")(?=.*"+struct+") 
   (?=.*Volume)")
            k = cohens_d(volumes_c, volumes_k)
            meand = volumes_c.mean()
            result_df = pd.Dataframe(
{
     "Cohen's norm": some result
     "Mean Value": meand
}
)
            return k
```

function select_volumes gives me the result:

```
Left-Amygdala_Volume_mm3   -0.29729
dtype: float64
Left-Hippocampus_Volume_mm3    0.33139
dtype: float64
Left-Lateral-Ventricle_Volume_mm3   -0.111853
dtype: float64
Left-Pallidum_Volume_mm3    0.28857
dtype: float64
Left-Putamen_Volume_mm3    0.696645
dtype: float64
Left-Thalamus-Proper_Volume_mm3    0.772492
dtype: float64
Right-Amygdala_Volume_mm3   -0.358333
dtype: float64
Right-Hippocampus_Volume_mm3    0.275668
dtype: float64
Right-Lateral-Ventricle_Volume_mm3   -0.092283
dtype: float64
Right-Pallidum_Volume_mm3    0.279258
dtype: float64
Right-Putamen_Volume_mm3    0.484879
dtype: float64
Right-Thalamus-Proper_Volume_mm3    0.809775
dtype: float64
```

I want Left-Amygdala_Volume_mm3 ... be the row with value -0.29729 with column name Cohen's d be the column for every Select_list:
[example, how dataframe should looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhrMW.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you know in advance how many columns you are going to need?

Comment: As a new user, you really should read [ask]. You would find advices on how to ask good question that would get nice and precise answers. Here without some sample data on which we can run your current code, it is really hard to guess how we can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: @Emil, i don't know how much columns there will be, because number of features could vary.

Comment: @SergeBallesta edited, thanks. Added my dataframe

Comment: What do you mean by adding column by columns? Do you mean that you go through a column in the old dataframe and then add it to the new one (if it meets some requirement)? And just to make sure: are you planning on adding the whole column once you select it or just some variables from it? The reason that I'm asking this is that every column should have the same length in a dataframe.

Comment: @Emil, i want a value k be a column, and element of Select_list be a raws.

Comment: Ok, I can see part of the dataframe. But I still cannot understand what column you want to add to what dataframe and when. It is certainly evident for **you** but how could **I** guess. Try to read your question, imaginig that you have no context below what is written here, and try to add enough information for the question to be *self contained*.

Comment: For example what does `cohens_d` return? A single value, a string, an array, a full dataframe? It matters as you say that you want it to be a *column*

Comment: @SergeBallesta added

Comment: And what should the resulting dataframe look like?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I want Left-Amygdala_Volume_mm3 ... be the row with value -0.29729 with column name Cohen's, for all Select_list and Side lists.

Comment: Please show an example with 2 or 3 lines and 2 or 3 columns. No matter if the data is wrong or even non sensitive, but I cannot imagine what it should be.

Comment: @SergeBallesta link in the text in the end

Comment: Ok, I now understand what it should be, but the number of columns is fixed here and will be 2.

Comment: @SergeBallesta ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write to pd.Dataframe inside a function:

```
k = cohens_d(volumes_c, volumes_k)
meand = volumes_c.mean()    
volumes_df.append([cohen.index[0],cohen.values[0], meand)
return volumes_df
```

and out of a function I call pd.Dataframe with:

```
finaldf=pd.DataFrame(select_volumes(control,patolog))
finaldf.columns=['Structure','Cohensd','Meand')
```

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot really understand how and where, but you showed that somewhere in the function you were able to build a float64 Series containing for example `Left-Amygdala_Volume_mm3` as index and `-0.29729` as value. And I assume that at the same time, you have the value of `meand` for the same index value.

More exactly I will assume:

```
k = pd.Series([-0.29729], dtype=np.float64,index=['Left-Amygdala_Volume_mm3'])
```

because it prints as:

```
print(k)

Left-Amygdala_Volume_mm3   -0.29729
dtype: float64
```

At the same time, I assume that `meand` is also a similar Series. So we will access its value as `meand.iloc[0]` (lets say value is 9174.1)

You should combine them to build the content of a row:

```
row = k.reset_index().iloc[0].tolist() + [meand.iloc[0]]
```

In the example we have `row`: `['Left-Amygdala_Volume_mm3', -0.29729, 9174.1]`

So you now need to build a large list of that rows:

```
def select_volumes(group_c,group_k):
    Select_list = ["Amygdala", "Hippocampus", "Lateral-Ventricle", 
"Pallidum", "Putamen", "Thalamus"]
    Side = ["Left", "Right"]
    data = []
    for s in Side:
        for struct in Select_list:
            volumes_c = group_c.filter(regex="^(?=.*"+s+")(?=.*"+struct+") 
   (?=.*Volume)")
            volumes_k = group_k.filter(regex="^(?=.*"+s+")(?=.*"+struct+") 
   (?=.*Volume)")
            k = cohens_d(volumes_c, volumes_k)
            meand = volumes_c.mean()

            # build a row of result df
            data.append(k.reset_index().iloc[0].tolist() + [meand.iloc[0]])

    # after the loop combine the rows into a dataframe and return it:
    result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['index', "Cohen's d", 'Mean']).set_index('index')
    return result
```

Comment: Mean column has a wrong value, it has a Series, instead of float/int
`index  
Left-Amygdala_Volume_mm3 -0.297290 Left-Amygdala_Volume_mm3 1506.961538 dtype:..`

Comment: @PatrickHellman Then we can access its value with `.iloc[0]`. See my edit